# How Does the Zero Trust Paradigm Work at Nucleon EDR?

Tags: security, endpoint, malware-detection, antimalware, nucleon

I work with Nucleon EDR, and I want to understand how the Zero Trust paradigm works.

Answer (score 0):

The absorption mode is the default mode activated during the installation of the Nucleon EDR agent. It involves absorbing the user's activities on the Endpoint. Indeed, it is a learning mode that allows listing all user business activities to create security rules. This mode also enables the automatic creation of rules when an event is blocked by an existing rule. Each new rule is automatically added to the "Absorption" application, which is empty by default.

During this mode, the artificial intelligence embedded in the agents absorbs, analyzes, and creates Zero-Trust hardening rules based on the behavior of users and servers.